# Is <output for=""> used for anything?

Tags: html, forms, metadata

HTML 5 introduced the [output](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-output-element) element, which has a `for` attribute defined as follows:

> The for content attribute allows an explicit relationship to be made between the result of a calculation and the elements that represent the values that went into the calculation or that otherwise influenced the calculation. The for attribute, if specified, must contain a string consisting of an unordered set of unique space-separated tokens that are case-sensitive, each of which must have the value of an ID of an element in the same Document.

Are there any browsers or applications which use the value of this element, and if so for what? It's a neat idea but I'm not sure how it actually plays out.

Comment: There's [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700499/what-is-the-purpose-of-for-attribute-in-output-element) that asks, quite simply, if there's any point in using `for`. I'm not sure if it's a duplicate, but it might be because at the end of the day, both questions ask if the `for` attribute has any functional purpose (beyond semantics anyway).

Comment: @BoltClock: Related, yes (+1), but I'm questioning neither the value of semantics -- actually I'm a strong proponent -- in general, nor of the `output` element in particular (which I use in my coding). I'd just like to know what use things might make of this metadata, or if any such exist. (That, plus I don't think we're suppose to mark questions as duplicates of other unanswered questions.)

Comment: @BoltClock I would mark this as a duplicate (and reopen the other one): the other question boils down to this. That said, this is the better posed question.